# How to fix error while publish asp.net website to ftp server

Tags: asp.net, publish

I have made a **ASP.NET** website using **Visual Studio 2017**. It successfully builds without any errors but while publishing it to remote FTP server it fails with the following error:

> Build started: Project: wordacus_website, Configuration: Release Any
>   CPU ------ 1>  wordacus_website ->
>   C:\Users\ss\source\repos\wordacus_website\wordacus_website\bin\wordacus_website.dll
>   2>------ Publish started: Project: wordacus_website, Configuration:
>   Release Any CPU ------ 2>Connecting to
>   ftp://198.37.116.26/d:\DZHosts\LocalUser\Nasheet999... 2>Unable to
>   create the Web site
>   'ftp://198.37.116.26/d:/DZHosts/LocalUser/Nasheet999'.  Cannot create
>   folder "Nasheet999". 2>
>   ========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
>   ========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
>
> and while opening the site it gives this error
>
> Server Error in '/' Application. Compilation Error Description: An
>   error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to
>   service this request. Please review the following specific error
>   details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS2011: Error opening response file
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\517ae5b5\67eacfe7\z2u3thth.cmdline'
>
> Source Error:
>
> [No relevant source lines]
>
> Source File:    Line: 0

ERROR report generated after publish failure

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. --->
>   System.Exception: Build failed. Check the Output window for more
>   details.    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean
>   includeTaskCanceledExceptions)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Publish.PublishService.VsWebProjectPublish.<>c__DisplayClass43_0.b__2()
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.ApplicationCapabilities.Publish.ViewModel.ProfileSelectorViewModel.d__127.MoveNext()
>   ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Exception: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.<---

I tried changing target and local .NET Framework version but no result.

Comment: Looks like your ftp account does not has the permission to create folders. Connect to your ftp site using any client e.g. FileZilla and then try creating folder `Nasheet999`

Comment: it succesfully published on file system but when transferring over ftp using file zilla as u mentioned it gives error.Command: STOR 
Error: Critical file transfer error
Command: CWD /bin/roslyn
Response: 550 The system cannot find the path specified.